# python2.7 install MySQL-python in virtualenv error "failed with exit status 2"

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv

[image]

In virtualenv , I can't setup packages some like `MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe` .

platform: win10 x64  python2.7.12  mysql

Comment: Thou shalt post the error as text!

Comment: And post the output of the actual installation (as text).

Comment: I know the reason of “failed with exit status 2” . In windows,we can set up  MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe.     But in virtualenv ,how can set up MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

Answer (score 0):

you can try `MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe` download site:  http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

Comment: In virtualenv,  I can't setup packages  MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

Comment: @AtsukonLee  you can Copy MySQL-Python into a Windows virtualenv.